# Python | Plotting & fitting a data fit in the form (1/A)e^(-x/A) in which A is a constant

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, exponential, trendline

[image: raw data]

After a lot of searching and being unable to find an answer i choose to place my question here.

How do i fit an exponential function in the form of y=(1/A)e^(-x/A) to the shown data and plot this function? I still need some getting used to fitting in Python. Help will be more than appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you already try [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)? If you found the above link but don't know how to use it, is it possible to share the data used to generate the image you have linked in your question?

Comment: I understand that upper left datum to mean that you have observed about 160 events with lifetimes just a little bit more than zero. Is that right?

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! I have tried playing around with SciPy, no good results yet. The thing i need seems a bit too different from the examples which are out there. Plus i'm not that familiar with fitting anyway, all i have managed to do is a gauss fit & linear regression so far... The data used can be found here: https://pastebin.com/i3H4ZfLQ

Answer (score 1):

Looks like i figured it out.

```
def exponential_fit(x, a, c):
"""
Logarithmic fit used for the MuonLab life time measurements.
:param x:
:param a:
:param c:
:return:
"""
return (1/a)*np.exp(-x/a)+c
```

def logarithmic_fit_plot(x, y): # WIP
    font = {'family': 'normal',
            'weight': 'bold',
            'size': 20}

```
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
xdata = x
ydata = y
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, '.', label='sample')
popt, pcov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(exponential_fit, xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xdata, exponential_fit(xdata, *popt), 'r-',
         label=r"$\frac{1}{\tau_0}e^{\frac{-x}{\tau_0}}, \tau_0=%5.3f, c=%5.3f$" % tuple(popt))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Sadly it doesn't fit the data very well, but that's just a math problem i guess.

Answer (score 1):

This code produces a decent fit.

```
first = True
lifetimes = []
counts = []
with open('Werkverkeer.txt') as w:
    next(w)
    for line in w:
        _, life, count = line.rstrip().split()
        life, count = float(life), int(count)
        if count==0:
            continue
        lifetimes.append(life-0.005)
        counts.append(count)

probs = [_/sum(counts) for _ in counts]
print (probs)

from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from scipy.stats import expon
from numpy import exp

def residual(params, X, data):
    model = [expon.cdf(x+0.005, scale=params[0])-expon.cdf(x-0.005, scale=params[0]) for x in X]
    return [d-m for (d,m) in zip(data, model)]

r = leastsq(residual, [140], args=(lifetimes, probs))
estimate = r[0][0]
print (estimate)

fitted = [expon.cdf(x+0.005, scale=estimate)-expon.cdf(x-0.005, scale=estimate) for x in lifetimes]
print(fitted)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(lifetimes, probs, 'r.')
plt.plot(lifetimes, fitted, 'b-')

plt.show()
```

[image: curve fit]

Things to note:

- Rather than fitting to `counts` I've fitted to normalised `counts`, which are estimates of probabilities, because the counts are really a way of getting at an estimate of the probability density function for the lifetimes.
- Because I'm using counts I need to fit the areas under the density function, for a given value of the parameter, between the boundaries of the bins. Hence, the line `model =`.
- As usual, the final line in `residual` returns the difference between the observed probabilities (based on counts) and the provisionally calculated probabilities.

`leastsq` returns a value of 0.0497646352872 for the parameter.